# Best Practice Linq driven Property

Tags: c#, linq

The Property Grade/GradeLinq of Student Class is driven by Points and scoring List.

I found two different Way to calculate the Grade. Shown below as Grade and GradeLinq

What is the better Practice for a good Class design. Provide dis/advantages or better solutions.

The Scoring Class

```
public class Scoring
{
    public int minScale { get; set; }
    public int maxScale { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StandardID { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public static List<Scoring> sc { get; set; }
    public string GradeLinq
    {
        get
        {
            return sc?.Find(w => w.minScale < Points && w.maxScale > Points).Grade;
        }
    }
}

var scoringList = new List<Scoring>
{
    new Scoring { maxScale=100, minScale=85, Grade ="A" },
    new Scoring { maxScale=84, minScale=70, Grade ="B" },
    new Scoring { maxScale=69, minScale=50, Grade ="C" },
    new Scoring { maxScale=49, minScale=40, Grade ="D" },
    new Scoring { maxScale=39, minScale=25, Grade ="E" },
    new Scoring { maxScale=24, minScale=0, Grade ="F" },
};



var studentList = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", StandardID =1, Points = 88 },
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin", StandardID =1, Points = 60 },
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill", StandardID =2, Points = 61 },
    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram",  StandardID =2, Points = 99 },
    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron", Points = 10 }
};


void Main()
{
    Student.sc = scoringList;
    studentList.ForEach(f => f.Grade = scoringList.Find(w => w.minScale < f.Points && w.maxScale > f.Points).Grade);
}
```

Comment: btw .Find and .ForEach are List methods. I don't see any LINQ methods

Answer (score 1):

Since grade is a property strictly related to the student entity that logic should be placed within the student class. For your example designing the student entity within the gradelinq property produce an easier to read and to mantain code.
You also don't pollute the business core logic within data manipolation operation once you need to use the grade property.